# Is there a drawback to using \setstretch outside the preamble?

Tags: front-matter, setspace

The [setspace package](https://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) source indicates:

> Three commands, `\singlespacing`, `\onehalfspacing`, and `\doublespacing`, are for use in the preamble to set the overall spacing for the document.  If a different spacing is required then the `\setstretch{baselinestretch}` command can be used in the preamble to set the baselinestretch appropriately.

The implication seems to be that the commands are not meant to be used outside the preamble – but in practice, it appears to work.

This is useful, because in most situations one would want to keep normal spacing on `\maketitle` and `\tableofcontents`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\setstretch{1.5}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Will using `\setstretch` outside the preamble cause problems, as the documentation would suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about a global change, mid document, you can always use an environment for a temporary change.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Test}
\setstretch{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{singlespace}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\end{singlespace}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

This would seem to provide the same result as the OP's MWE.

Comment: Thank you – I'm still curious to know if it's allowable to use the setspace commands outside the preamble, but that's certainly a good solution to this particular problem.